# Printing a UPS rate array

Tags: php, arrays

Here is what I have as a result using print_r($rate);

> Array
>   (
>
> > [ups] => Array
> >            (
> >
> > > ```
> > >        [03] => 11.06
> > >    )
> > > ```
> > >
> > > )

What I am attempting to do unsuccessfully:

> echo($rate['03']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
echo $rate['ups']['03'];
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple. Just couldn't figure it out!

Comment: @user1524441 If this helped you, please hit the outline of a checkmark to mark it as correct. Thanks!